# How to access C$ share in a network?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, share, smb

Considering I have admin access to a machine, can I remotely access the default C$ share in Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: Wikipedia has an exhaustive article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In theory yes:

```
\\servername\C$
```

...but I have had problems with this, and you shouldn't really modify access permissions for the default administrative share. It is best to create a new share that you can control precisely.

Comment: ok, but I suppose there must be a way to access it, isn't?

Comment: Why do you need to? Just create a new share (Right-Click on C: in explorer -> sharing & security -> new share) that you can absolutely control. Like I say, you shouldn't really play around with default admistrative share or you can break various services...

Comment: I'm working on a security tool, written in C#. One of the features that I would like to implement is that, once you have admin rights to the machine, you can access it even if no shares were manually created (as you suggested)

Comment: I see, fair enough. How are you authenticating against the remote machine? And are you dealing with on a domain/in a workgroup or both?

Comment: I have re-tagged the question with C# to help you get the right focus

Comment: Initially it's not over a domain, just a single machine, with a single ou a couple of users, but a singles machine.

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to be able to authenticate as a member of the local Administrators group. Therefore if your program is not running under a user account that is in this group, you will need to supply credentials... (and possibly even if it is, I have never tried this programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to access it with:

`\\netbiosname\c$`

Comment: Have you tried this? Over a network it doesn't work...

Comment: Actually, it does work. I do it all the time. I work in IT. The key is to access it as the correct user account. When you're logged in as a local user account on a PC, and you type it into the address bar in the Explorer, it will try to access it as that account. The other PC can't validate that. Edit: You can map it, and set the credentials as the user account on the other PC. Or, you can use a domain account that is part of the Administrators group on the other PC.

Comment: @djdanlib - I tried that. The scenario I have is: from alice-pc logged in with alice user I try to access \\bob-pc\C$ using Bob's admin account: BOB-PC\Bob, but it says "Access Denied"

Comment: @jyzuz - can you try running Explorer as Bob (go into Start Menu, type `Explorer`, right-click and click `run as...`, then putting \\bob-pc\c$ into the address bar of that Explorer window? Another thought... are bob-pc and Bob members of a domain, and are you logging in with DOMAIN\Bob in the username field? Is BOB-PC\Bob the admin account as you said, or DOMAIN\Bob?

Comment: I see. You also have to configure the firewall to allow SMB through, and you may need to edit the local security policy as well.